# erro no post http

Tags: http, post, angular, typescript, ionic2

Amigos, gostaria de ter o método salvar na própria classe, e não estou conseguindo, sou iniciante na linguagem typeScript.

```
    import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';


    @Injectable()

    export class Usuario {

      http: Http;
      nome: string;
      apelido: string;
      email: string;
      tel: string;
      senha: string;

      salvar(usuario){
        this.http.post("http://localhost:5000/users",JSON.stringify(usuario), {})
                 .toPromise()
                 .then(res => console.log(res.json().data))
                 .catch();
      }

    }
```

recebo o erro:

```
    browser_adapter.js:84 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
```

Comment: Já olhou antes o seu `chmod` (tipo permissão)? ele esta dizendo de erro undefined está vazio.

Comment: já sim, as permissões estão normais.

Comment: Parece que ele não está aceitando seu "this.http". Todos os exemplos que vi e em um código que fiz seta o http no construtor, não tive tempo de testar ainda, mas uso assim constructor(private http:Http) {}. Mesmo vazio como pode ver neste link http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-2-making-rest-http-requests-like-a-pro/

Comment: exatamente @AndréVicente, porém quando tento instanciar um objeto Usuario, "let usuario = new Usuario()" , ele da erro, pois pedi para passar o http como parâmetro no construtor. Minha ideia é setar os atributos no objeto Usuario e salvar no banco o mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esqueceste-te de injectar o `Http`.

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
  }
```

E depois no teu `AppModule`

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

...

 imports:[
  HttpModule,
],
...
```